Numeric alignment in table with multicolumn and multirow
I have trouble in aligning the numeric value at the dot, or at the "x" symbol.
I tried to format the columns as S columns from siunitx, but it did not work.
Some columns appear to be already aligned, but some others (as ...) are not aligned, and i can't understand why.
Any hints?
Here my result:

and the minimal functional code that generated it:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=1cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{multirow}

\newcommand{\scinot}[1]{
\begingroup
\sisetup{scientific-notation=true, round-mode = figures, round-precision = 4, retain-zero-exponent = true}
\num{#1}
\endgroup}

\newcommand{\sciperc}[1]{
\begingroup
\sisetup{scientific-notation=false, round-mode = figures, round-precision = 4}
\num{#1}
\endgroup}

\begin{document}

\begin{table*}
    \centering
    \caption{tuned embedded models parameters}
    \label{tab:shaker_param_02}
    \resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{
    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|} 
    \hline
    \multirow{2}{*}{\textbf{UML model }} & \multirow{2}{*}{\textbf{FR / FA Method }} & \multirow{2}{*}{\textbf{PF [\%] }} & \multirow{2}{*}{\textbf{Variance}} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textbf{Mean }} & \multirow{2}{*}{\textbf{Reactivity }} & \multirow{2}{*}{\textbf{Inference Time [s]}} \\ 
    \cline{5-6}
     &  &  &  & \textbf{\textit{Train signal}} & \textbf{\textit{Test Signal}} &  &  \\ 
    \hline
\multirow{4}{*}{KMeans} &  None & \sciperc{100.0} & \scinot{6.062661721482947e-06} & \scinot{0.000949154244728405} & \scinot{0.9798509162365615} & \scinot{0.9789017619918331} &  \scinot{0.00022314522427377976} \\
\cline{2-8}
 & AER & \sciperc{45.714285714285715} & \scinot{2.505779691742467e-06} & \scinot{0.0010408974892296657} & \scinot{0.9673505027851046} & \scinot{0.966309605295875} &  \scinot{0.00020191063834923257} \\
\cline{2-8}
 & AEA & \sciperc{121.42857142857142} & \scinot{3.880979447727627e-06} & \scinot{0.0008432529137581275} & \scinot{0.9738479384052703} & \scinot{0.9730046854915122} &  \scinot{0.00020264352632872162} \\
\cline{2-8}
 & PCA & \sciperc{5.714285714285714} & \scinot{1.4319211681963625e-06} & \scinot{0.0022098608512454883} & \scinot{0.9418739636052269} & \scinot{0.9396641027539814} &  \scinot{0.00018947684113235718} \\
\hline
\multirow{4}{*}{DBSCAN} &  None & \sciperc{100.0} & \scinot{6.763667376184677e-06} & \scinot{0.0017832590349845616} & \scinot{0.9904638515555892} & \scinot{0.9886805925206047} &  \scinot{1.192476205120516e-05} \\
\cline{2-8}
 & AER & \sciperc{14.285714285714285} & \scinot{2.3026844330884296e-06} & \scinot{0.0005396012801494134} & \scinot{0.9601076157305578} & \scinot{0.9595680144504084} &  \scinot{7.14872427691984e-06} \\
\cline{2-8}
 & AEA & \sciperc{121.42857142857142} & \scinot{1.424036970251951e-06} & \scinot{0.0012843101455370604} & \scinot{0.9660648717932967} & \scinot{0.9647805616477596} &  \scinot{8.36918208376771e-06} \\
\cline{2-8}
 & PCA & \sciperc{2.857142857142857} & \scinot{2.1273673271229781e-07} & \scinot{0.0005905540627858245} & \scinot{0.9505614027392001} & \scinot{0.9499708486764142} &  \scinot{6.402803770598875e-06} \\
\hline
\multirow{4}{*}{GMM} &  None & \sciperc{100.0} & \scinot{4.0167898186029493e-16} & \scinot{3.1683489569369825e-09} & \scinot{0.9689023453095984} & \scinot{0.9689023421412495} &  \scinot{2.2649765014648438e-05} \\
\cline{2-8}
 & AER & \sciperc{14.285714285714285} & \scinot{5.169515183614666e-10} & \scinot{6.81149428700943e-06} & \scinot{0.9372525843334348} & \scinot{0.9372457728391478} &  \scinot{7.838681579786098e-06} \\
\cline{2-8}
 & AEA & \sciperc{121.42857142857142} & \scinot{6.770236116748827e-09} & \scinot{1.1163708952829429e-05} & \scinot{0.9433017982669939} & \scinot{0.9432906345580411} &  \scinot{2.9796189433892056e-05} \\
\cline{2-8}
 & PCA & \sciperc{2.857142857142857} & \scinot{3.629804266414173e-11} & \scinot{6.4116843184521225e-06} & \scinot{0.9042026931074973} & \scinot{0.9041962814231789} &  \scinot{5.809440490133893e-06} \\
\hline
\multirow{4}{*}{nuSVM} &  None & \sciperc{100.0} & \scinot{0.02316323368773742} & \scinot{0.31649999492346187} & \scinot{1.0} & \scinot{0.6835000050765381} &  \scinot{3.5440806790563455e-06} \\
\cline{2-8}
 & AER & \sciperc{14.285714285714285} & \scinot{0.007991048611295305} & \scinot{0.06832241388336166} & \scinot{1} & \scinot{0.9316775861166382} &  \scinot{7.911510406199759e-07} \\
\cline{2-8}
 & AEA & \sciperc{132.85714285714286} & \scinot{0.0021082448459297325} & \scinot{0.057987027623221964} & \scinot{1.0} & \scinot{0.9420129723767781} &  \scinot{1.1936261339586265e-06} \\
\cline{2-8}
 & PCA & \sciperc{2.857142857142857} & \scinot{0.0023467695850921825} & \scinot{0.06303640448303008} & \scinot{1.0} & \scinot{0.93696359551697} &  \scinot{8.317818595665444e-07} \\
\hline
\multirow{4}{*}{IForest} &  None & \sciperc{100.0} & \scinot{0.00455722190040741} & \scinot{0.11764135059845676} & \scinot{0.9912841292404345} & \scinot{0.8736427786419778} &  \scinot{5.674515506462269e-06} \\
\cline{2-8}
 & AER & \sciperc{64.28571428571429} & \scinot{0.015626591241184054} & \scinot{0.21792505474267637} & \scinot{0.9741811664093143} & \scinot{0.756256111666638} &  \scinot{5.252108313263038e-06} \\
\cline{2-8}
 & AEA & \sciperc{121.42857142857142} & \scinot{0.01543846982076953} & \scinot{0.179240193554547} & \scinot{0.9822304609593677} & \scinot{0.8029902674048207} &  \scinot{5.272807032349026e-06} \\
\cline{2-8}
 & PCA & \sciperc{100.0} & \scinot{0.011907985922966867} & \scinot{0.2532571648969081} & \scinot{0.9779494081815806} & \scinot{0.7246922432846725} &  \scinot{5.813273586260927e-06} \\
\hline
\multirow{4}{*}{LOF} &  None & \sciperc{100.0} & \scinot{6.125186628833738e-06} & \scinot{0.00041219944293657156} & \scinot{0.9877777958128381} & \scinot{0.9873655963699015} &  \scinot{8.029186457299727e-05} \\
\cline{2-8}
 & AER & \sciperc{14.285714285714285} & \scinot{1.9469705e-06} & \scinot{0.0004461435} & \scinot{0.9551045} & \scinot{0.9546583294868469} &  \scinot{2.7682620229445086e-06} \\
\cline{2-8}
 & AEA & \sciperc{125.71428571428571} & \scinot{1.0774247e-06} & \scinot{0.00021695245} & \scinot{0.96795046} & \scinot{0.9677335023880005} &  \scinot{7.074362212055366e-06} \\
\cline{2-8}
 & PCA & \sciperc{2.857142857142857} & \scinot{1.3252566904129441e-07} & \scinot{0.0004034319581788697} & \scinot{0.9117495807640277} & \scinot{0.9113461488058489} &  \scinot{3.4183551260896053e-06} \\
\hline
\end{tabular}}
\end{table*}


\end{document}


Why are you using \num here? Is has nothing to do with table alignment. Why not an S column, and no \sciX macros.

And one should never use \resiebox to scale down a table, what is poor design.

@daleif i tried to use S columns, but there is some sort of conflict with \multicolumn

@daleif the resizebox is just here to produce the minimal example, it is not present in my document

It should not be in the minimal example either. Remeber novice users also come by and might thing that this is a good desgin choice. Hint, it is not.

Here is something more cleaned up
I outcommented all the \cline's as they do not help with the design of the table (makes it harder to read). Personally I'd also remove the vertical lines, and use the booktabs lines for the remaining horizontal lines.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=1cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{multirow}

\usepackage[tableposition=top]{caption}


% \newcommand{\scinot}[1]{
% \begingroup
% \sisetup{scientific-notation=true, round-mode = figures, round-precision = 4, retain-zero-exponent = true}
% \num{#1}
% \endgroup}

% \newcommand{\sciperc}[1]{
% \begingroup
% \sisetup{scientific-notation=false, round-mode = figures, round-precision = 4}
% \num{#1}
% \endgroup}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\centering
    \caption{tuned embedded models parameters}
    \label{tab:shaker_param_02}
    \footnotesize
    \begin{tabular}{
      |
      c|
      c|
      S[table-format=3.4,round-mode = places, round-precision = 4] |
      S[table-format=1.4,round-mode = places, round-precision = 4]|
      S[table-format=1.4,round-mode = places, round-precision = 4]|
      S[table-format=1.4,round-mode = places, round-precision = 4]|
      S[table-format=1.4,round-mode = places, round-precision = 4]|
      S[table-format=1.4,round-mode = places, round-precision = 4]|
      } 
      \hline
      {\multirow{2}{*}{\textbf{UML model }}}
      &
        {\multirow{2}{*}{\textbf{FR / FA Method }}}
      &
        {\multirow{2}{*}{\textbf{PF [\%] }}}
      &
        {\multirow{2}{*}{\textbf{Variance}}}
      &
        \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textbf{Mean}}
      &
        {\multirow{2}{*}{\textbf{Reactivity}}}
      &
        {\multirow{2}{*}{\textbf{Inference Time [s]}}}
      \\ 
      \cline{5-6}
      &  &  &  & {\textbf{\textit{Train signal}}} & {\textbf{\textit{Test Signal}}} &  &  \\ 
      \hline
      
\multirow{4}{*}{KMeans}  & None & 100.0              & 6.062661721482947e-06  & 0.000949154244728405   & 0.9798509162365615 & 0.9789017619918331 & 0.00022314522427377976 \\
%\cline{2-8}
                         & AER  & 45.714285714285715 & 2.505779691742467e-06  & 0.0010408974892296657  & 0.9673505027851046 & 0.966309605295875  & 0.00020191063834923257 \\
%\cline{2-8}
                         & AEA  & 121.42857142857142 & 3.880979447727627e-06  & 0.0008432529137581275  & 0.9738479384052703 & 0.9730046854915122 & 0.00020264352632872162 \\
%\cline{2-8}
                         & PCA  & 5.714285714285714  & 1.4319211681963625e-06 & 0.0022098608512454883  & 0.9418739636052269 & 0.9396641027539814 & 0.00018947684113235718 \\
\hline
\multirow{4}{*}{DBSCAN}  & None & 100.0              & 6.763667376184677e-06  & 0.0017832590349845616  & 0.9904638515555892 & 0.9886805925206047 & 1.192476205120516e-05  \\
%\cline{2-8}
                         & AER  & 14.285714285714285 & 2.3026844330884296e-06 & 0.0005396012801494134  & 0.9601076157305578 & 0.9595680144504084 & 7.14872427691984e-06   \\
%\cline{2-8}
                         & AEA  & 121.42857142857142 & 1.424036970251951e-06  & 0.0012843101455370604  & 0.9660648717932967 & 0.9647805616477596 & 8.36918208376771e-06   \\
%\cline{2-8}
                         & PCA  & 2.857142857142857  & 2.1273673271229781e-07 & 0.0005905540627858245  & 0.9505614027392001 & 0.9499708486764142 & 6.402803770598875e-06  \\
\hline
\multirow{4}{*}{GMM}     & None & 100.0              & 4.0167898186029493e-16 & 3.1683489569369825e-09 & 0.9689023453095984 & 0.9689023421412495 & 2.2649765014648438e-05 \\
%\cline{2-8}
                         & AER  & 14.285714285714285 & 5.169515183614666e-10  & 6.81149428700943e-06   & 0.9372525843334348 & 0.9372457728391478 & 7.838681579786098e-06  \\
%\cline{2-8}
                         & AEA  & 121.42857142857142 & 6.770236116748827e-09  & 1.1163708952829429e-05 & 0.9433017982669939 & 0.9432906345580411 & 2.9796189433892056e-05 \\
%\cline{2-8}
                         & PCA  & 2.857142857142857  & 3.629804266414173e-11  & 6.4116843184521225e-06 & 0.9042026931074973 & 0.9041962814231789 & 5.809440490133893e-06  \\
\hline
\multirow{4}{*}{nuSVM}   & None & 100.0              & 0.02316323368773742    & 0.31649999492346187    & 1.0                & 0.6835000050765381 & 3.5440806790563455e-06 \\
%\cline{2-8}
                         & AER  & 14.285714285714285 & 0.007991048611295305   & 0.06832241388336166    & 1                  & 0.9316775861166382 & 7.911510406199759e-07  \\
%\cline{2-8}
                         & AEA  & 132.85714285714286 & 0.0021082448459297325  & 0.057987027623221964   & 1.0                & 0.9420129723767781 & 1.1936261339586265e-06 \\
%\cline{2-8}
                         & PCA  & 2.857142857142857  & 0.0023467695850921825  & 0.06303640448303008    & 1.0                & 0.93696359551697   & 8.317818595665444e-07  \\
\hline
\multirow{4}{*}{IForest} & None & 100.0              & 0.00455722190040741    & 0.11764135059845676    & 0.9912841292404345 & 0.8736427786419778 & 5.674515506462269e-06  \\
%\cline{2-8}
                         & AER  & 64.28571428571429  & 0.015626591241184054   & 0.21792505474267637    & 0.9741811664093143 & 0.756256111666638  & 5.252108313263038e-06  \\
%\cline{2-8}
                         & AEA  & 121.42857142857142 & 0.01543846982076953    & 0.179240193554547      & 0.9822304609593677 & 0.8029902674048207 & 5.272807032349026e-06  \\
%\cline{2-8}
                         & PCA  & 100.0              & 0.011907985922966867   & 0.2532571648969081     & 0.9779494081815806 & 0.7246922432846725 & 5.813273586260927e-06  \\
\hline
\multirow{4}{*}{LOF}     & None & 100.0              & 6.125186628833738e-06  & 0.00041219944293657156 & 0.9877777958128381 & 0.9873655963699015 & 8.029186457299727e-05  \\
%\cline{2-8}
                         & AER  & 14.285714285714285 & 1.9469705e-06          & 0.0004461435           & 0.9551045          & 0.9546583294868469 & 2.7682620229445086e-06 \\
%\cline{2-8}
                         & AEA  & 125.71428571428571 & 1.0774247e-06          & 0.00021695245          & 0.96795046         & 0.9677335023880005 & 7.074362212055366e-06  \\
%\cline{2-8}
                         & PCA  & 2.857142857142857  & 1.3252566904129441e-07 & 0.0004034319581788697  & 0.9117495807640277 & 0.9113461488058489 & 3.4183551260896053e-06 \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}



Thanks a lot, man! This put me on the right track,  at the end I removed the vertical lines and used booktabs as you suggested
